# Scope of inline-svg elements' id='x' and <use xlink:href='#x' />

Tags: html, svg, scope

When having multiple inline `svg` in my document I have noticed that using `<use xlink:href="#id"/>` will reference the first defined element with `id="id"`, even when defined in another inline `svg`.

Somehow I was assuming the `id`/`xlink:href` scope was just the `svg` but it seems it is the whole document - which actually makes sense when thinking about it.

Example (red square in second svg should be green):

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<html><head></head><body>

<svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <defs>
    <rect id="foo" width="25" height="25" fill="red" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#foo" />
</svg>
<svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <defs>
    <rect id="foo" width="25" height="25" fill="green" />
    <rect id="bar" width="25" height="25" fill="blue" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#bar" x=25 />
  <use xlink:href="#foo" /> <!-- Not green but red! -->
</svg>

</body></html>
```

Is there a way to have `<use/>` elements only reference elements from the same `<svg>` somehow? Or would I have to create valid, document wide unique IDs?

Comment: No, ids must be unique throughout the whole document, otherwise the document is invalid

Comment: Yes, it actually makes sense. So what would be the alternative? Not using inline svg or is there another way?

Comment: You could make all the SVGs external then refer to them via file.svg#foo and file2.svg#foo

Comment: It just wouldn't fit my workflow. Designers had to put thought into and organize SVGs markup. Also most SVGs are unrelated to each other.
Right now my designers just export from their tools. SVGs get minified and thrown into a JS object in a built script. Finally they get inserted into the site's DOM via JavaScript.

Comment: you'll need to add an extra step either before or after minification to make all the ids globally unique then.

Comment: It's more complicated than that even. I can't get around an additional step right before inserting the SVG into the DOM. Making the IDs unique for each instance or moving all SVG's `<defs>` sections `filter`s, etc. in a separate SVG which is always inserted first.
Otherwise, if I'd insert the same SVG two times I'd again end up with duplicate IDs.

Comment: I could refer to `file.svg#foo` from my inline SVG if I also put the file on the server. But I'd load the same markup twice then (JS with all SVGs and the actual SVG file).